# setOnItemSelectedListener of spinner not executing

Tags: android

I am creating a spinner this way:

```
spinnerShared = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerShared);
    Resources res = getResources();
    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_row, arryList, res);
    spinnerShared.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

I want to get selected value this way:

```
    spinnerShared.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "onItemSelected executed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

I should get message "onItemSelected executed" in toast. But I am not getting the message.

Comment: Show what you have done

Comment: Cannot understand what you mean. I edited as much as I could. But still not sure where your first sentence starts and ends :-)

Comment: Actually i need the get selected item from spinner on setOnItemSelectedListener i have taken spinner in xml layout but setOnItemSelectedListener is not executing i have spreaded spinner upon a button click.

Comment: Can i see your CustomAdapter calss?

Comment: this is my custome adapter where i have taken layout name as spinner_row  CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_row, arryList, res);
    spinnerShared.setAdapter(customAdapter);

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner s1;
    String[] sports = {
            "Cricket",
            "Footbale",
            "Hockey",
            "Table Tennis",

    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //---Spinner View---
        s1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sports);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);

        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, 
            int arg2, long arg3) {
                int index = s1.getSelectedItemPosition(); Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "You have selected item : " + sports[index], 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            } 
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution of your problem is simple

setOnItemSelectedListener will execute when you click on any item of spinner
not when you click on button, So just try to change spinner value...